# ActiveReport 6 not working in Visual studio 2013 [OS Windows 10]

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, activereports

I installed ActiveReport 6 on my system.But am not able to add new ActiveReport to my project.
Do ActiveReport 6 works in Visual studio 2013?.And am using windows 10 OS.

Comment: Have you checked out the microsoft documentation for this? If yes, please mention what did you try and what didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ActiveReports 6 does not support Visual Studio 2013 or Windows 10 OS. 
ActiveReports 6 supports the following:

- **Microsoft Visual Studio**: 2005, 2008, or 2010
- **Operating System**: Windows® 2000, Windows® XP, Windows® NT 4.0, Windows ™ Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, or Windows Server 2008 R2.

To see what else is supported for ActiveReports 6, please refer to our [System Requirements](https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/Legacy/ActiveReports6/topic5.html).

Sincerely,

GrapeCity Support Team

https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact